# Count similar records

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

How do I write an SQL showing the number of films member 1 and 2 have in common?

MID=Member ID
FID=Film ID
Explanation of table below: Member 1 has films 2,3,5,17,21 on his list. Member 2 has films 5,14,18 on his list.

```
 1. MID ------ | FID
 2. M000001 | F000002
 3. M000001 | F000003
 4. M000001 | F000005
 5. M000001 | F000021
 6. M000002 | F000005
 7. M000002 | F000014
 8. M000002 | F000018
 9. M000003 | F000001
 10. M000003 | F000004
 11. M000003 |F000024
```

*sorry for the poor table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is the purpose so that as a member, I might see other members with a similar taste in films? Because that changes how it should be implemented.

Comment: yes @Ghost that is the purpose (roughly). As a movie rental business, I want to see which members have similar taste in films and hence recommend films to them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the number for all pairs, just do a self join:

```
select t1.mid, t2.mid, count(*)
from table as t1 inner join
     table as t2
     on t1.fid = t2.fid and t1.mid < t2.mid
group by t1.mid, t2.mid;
```

If you want to limit this just to two members, you can do:

```
select count(*)
from table as t1 inner join
     table as t2
     on t1.fid = t2.fid and
        t1.mid = 1 and
        t2.mid = 2;
```

Comment: I think "t1.mid < t2.mid" should be "t1.mid <> t2.mid"

Comment: No, using `<` avoids duplicates

Comment: @popovitsj You sure? :)

Comment: it'll only avoid duplicates when you have only two members... <> or != is way safer

Comment: @Ghost If you use <> you'll get `Mid=1, Mid=2, Fid=1` as well as `Mid=2, Mid=1, Fid=1`.

Comment: @BrettGreen Has nothing to do with being safe and will work just as well for more members.

Comment: It does not include matches for MIDs whose value is greater... so M1's listing will not include matches against M2.

Comment: @BrettGreen you should think about it a little longer I think.

Comment: You are correct popovitsj... it's whether you want to see all the permutations from both perspectives. Seems 'safer' in my opinion, because if I add a where clause using <... like 'WHERE t1.MID = 3'... it won't give me what I expect

Comment: @BrettGreen You're right that it depends on the requirements. If you want all *permutations*, you use `<>`, if you need all *combinations*, you use `<`.

Comment: @DavidTan . . . The second query provides that information.  The first generalizes to all pairs of members (which as popvitzj very correctly points out in the comments has non-repeated pairs).

Comment: Hi @popovitsj, thanks for replying. I'm new to sql. Does t1 in your reply mean table1? I only have 1 table right now called "list". This is a join table showing member 1's (M000001's) favourite films (F000002, 3, 5, 17, 21) and member 2's and member 3's. What i want to create is another table showing the number of films M000001 and M000002 have in common (in this case, 1); and subsequently do the same for M000001 with M000003 and M000002 with M000003. Thank you (:

Comment: @DavidTan it's not my answer, but t1 is a 'table alias' in this query. You should replace 'table' with your actual tablename. The other thing you talk about is best done by creating a VIEW, not by making another table.

Comment: @popovitsj thanks for your input again. I am using microsoft access 2013 and i dont think that VIEW is supported. Is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: @DavidTan please try to solve it yourself and create a new question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

With a subquery is one way.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE Mid = 2 AND Fid = t.Fid)
AND Mid = 1
```